# Get CPU processor speed via PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I needed to get number of CPU processor speed as a number.
I can't use any extra utility commands. I can use only cmd in Windows or Powershell.

`wmic cpu get name | select -Skip 1 | %{$_.Split(' ')[5];} | %{$_.Substring(0, 3)}`

Everything is performed correctly, except substring command 
[image]

Does it exist any easy approach to fix it? And why I get 4 warning for single value after split command?

Comment: `Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Select-Object -Expand MaxClockSpeed`

Comment: Or shortened `(GWMI Win32_Processor).MaxClockSpeed` or if you have at least PowerShell 3.0, `(GCIM Win32_Processor).MaxClockSpeed`.

Answer (score 5):

Don't parse `wmic` output unless you're pressed for performance (and even then you should do `(wmic cpu get maxclockspeed) -notlike '*maxclockspeed*'` rather than parse the processor name output).

Use [`Get-WmiObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-3.0) (all PowerShell versions) or [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-3.0) (PowerShell v3 or newer) with the [`Win32_Processor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processor) class and expand the relevant property (`MaxClockSpeed`).

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | Select-Object -Expand MaxClockSpeed
```

The value is in MHz.